# Upstart job not starting

Tags: boot, startup, upstart

Can someone help me with a startup script not starting? I started it with `initctl start startupScript`, and it works fine. But it wont start at startup (= virtualbox, and mount, doesnt execute). I need sleep, and I cannot fix this server bug, -_ I suspect something is wrong with mount, or sleep related to starting up.

I have done initctl reload-configuration to no avail.

```
start on filesystem
script
    wall /root/startup.txt
    eject /dev/sr0
    /bin/umount /dev/sdb2
    /bin/sleep 2s
    /bin/mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/VirtualBox
    /bin/sleep 5s
    VBoxManage startvm "Windows 7" --type headless
    /bin/sleep 25s
    /usr/local/bin/noip2
    wall /root/startupComplete.txt
end script

post-start script
end script
```

(EJECT0 === my usb modem)

(SDB2 === disk with virtualbox image)

(VIRTUALBOX START & NOIP EXECUTION)

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
start on startup
```

instead of

```
start on filesystem
```

worked for me (I geuss the filesystem variable not supported by our environment). I also recommend adding pre/post-script logging so that you can see to what point the script was successful.